# String(contentsOfURL:) in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, swift3

This code from before:

```
if let resultOfURL = try? String(contentsOfURL:myURL!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
```

Is now throwing this error:

```
'init' has been renamed to 'init(describing:)'
```

Any help? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Help yourself: Re-type `String(` and look in the code completion suggestions for the right syntax.

Comment: String(describing: <Subject>) was one of the completion suggestions, but I wasn't sure how to create a Subject that represented a URL with encoding. I also see there is a completion suggestion for contentsOf: / replacing contentsOfURL with simply contentsOf removes the error, but does not introduce "describing" to the call so I hadn't thought to try that. Will be testing with contentsOf: now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the Swift 3 Migration Guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/),

> Users may need to manually migrate calls to String(contentsOfURL:usedEncoding:) to String(contentsOf:usedEncoding:)

Comment: Bonus points for the link, which I should have had open already, and will now be my first place to search with any Swift -> Swift 3 oddities.