# Swift 3: "init has been renamed to init(describing)"

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to parse a webpage and access the title tag of the webpage. However, when I try to assign my variable `html` to `String(contentOfURL: ...)`, I get the error:

> init has been renamed to init(describing).

I tried putting this function inside of `init(describing)` and it still did not work? What is the issue that I am not seeing?

[image: init has been renamed to init(describing)]

Comment: Please check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39089259/6541007).

Comment: ^ Oh, my mistake! That worked.

Comment: Granted, it's not a very good error message.

Comment: Suggestion: Write yourself the same line char by char and use Autocompletion that may be helpful. Else, use the doc. Swift 3 did made a lot of changes in the naming of the method, but not Objective-C (which is still "quite" verbose), and you may find the Objective-C one quite easily, and then just switch on the doc to the Swift version.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!